# How to add Timeout option in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am looking to add a Timeout option in my Ruby script. If the script has been running for more than 1 day it is to exit.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution might be that you encapsulate your script in a [`Timeout`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.2/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html) block:

```
require 'timeout'

Timeout::timeout(86_400) do
  # Code that should be interrupted if it takes more than 1 day.
  # One day equals 24 * 60 * 60 = 86400 seconds.
end
```